# How can I add 2 html paths in my "tailwind.config.js"? Tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, html, path, tailwind-css

[This is, how my config file is right now. (see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x13Xp.png)

Is there any chance, to add a second html file on a different path?
The actual path is:

```
content: ["public/index.html"],
```

Is it possible to add a html path like:

```
content: ["public/index.html; public/info/contact.html"],?
```

Comment: For future reference, it would be better to paste your config file directly into your question instead of using a screenshot of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `content` value is an array of strings, so you might try:

```
content: ['public/index.html', 'public/info/contact.html']
```

You could also use the glob pattern to include all files under `public`.

```
content: ['./public/**/*.html']
```

More information: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration